# Puting an image in a rectangle in Android

Tags: android, image

I have an ImageView that is already on the screen, but I want to put a rectangle around it for collision detection. I've tried doing this:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         int[] l = new int[2];
            playerimage.getLocationOnScreen(l);
            int xxx = l[0];
            int yyy = l[1];
            int w = playerimage.getWidth();
            int h = playerimage.getHeight();
            int[] ll = new int[2];
            brickimg.getLocationOnScreen(l);
            int xxxx = l[0];
            int yyyy = l[1];
            int ww = playerimage.getWidth();
            int hh = playerimage.getHeight();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(xxx, yyy, w, h, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        canvas.drawRect(xxxx, yyyy, ww, hh, paint );
```

but it doesn't make a rectangle. Is there another way to put a rectangle around an image? I'm trying to do it for collision detection.

Comment: 1. Is it possible your instance of canvas isn't actually the size of the screen? IE. Are you drawing the player/bricks on the same canvas that you're trying to draw the rectangles? 2. Canvas drawing is done in reference to the local canvas coordinates, not the window's, so it's very likely you're drawing outside the boundaries of your canvas' View. 3. I suggest naming your variables better, as that's ridiculous to read.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Rect is what you are looking for?:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try this function.

```
public boolean collision(ImageView a, ImageView b){
    float bl = a.getY();
    float bt = a.getX();
    float br = a.getWidth() + bl;
    float bb = a.getHeight() + bt;
    float pl = b.getY();
    float pt = b.getX();
    float pr = b.getWidth() + pl;
    float pb = b.getHeight() + pt;
    if (bl <= pr && bl >= pl && bt >= pt && bt <= pb) {
        return true;

    } else if (br >= pl && br <= pr && bb >= pt && bb <= pb) {
        return true;
    } else if (bt <= pb && bt >= pt && br >= pl && br <= pr) {
        return true;
    } else if (bb >= pt && bb <= pb && bl >= pl && bl <= pr) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```